# Is a neutron attracted to a proton in an isolated system?

Tags: electrostatics, elementary-particles

As we know that if a neutral body comes near a charged body charges are induced on it and the nearer end experiences more force than the farther end, hence it attracts.

What happens if the neutral body is too small, e.g. if a neutron is near a proton in an isolated system. Will they be attracted to each other?

Answer (score 1):

**The neutron doesn't experience electric interactions with the proton, but it can experience magnetic interactions.**

That's actually a good question and it helps to illustrate the difference between microscopic and macroscopic phenomena. As you said, a neutral object can be polarized by an approaching charge, since the external charge produces a reordering of the free charges on the surface of the material (i.e. free electrons in a conductor). However, keep in mind these free charges are essentially related to the electrons of the object, that is, to its microscopic components its made of.

Since neutrons are subatomic particles with no electromagnetic charge, they cannot suffer this kind of polarization and thus do not feel attraction/repulsion towards charged particles like the proton. In other words, there aren't "free charges" on the surface of the neutron that could potentially produce an induced dipole on the neutron.

Nevertheless, it is worth noting that the neutron is indeed attracted to the proton via the **nuclear force** (not to be confused with the strong nuclear force), via a mechanism called pion exchange.

Edit: (adding more information to complement the answer)

While it is true that quarks do possess charge, the fact is that quarks in a neutron (which add up to zero) are so closely bound together by the strong nuclear force that they cannot feel the electromagnetic force of the proton. However, I'm not aware if there could be a extreme case where an external electric field could indeed affect the very quarks in neutron.

Nevertheless, there's indeed a contribution from the quarks themselves to the neutron, and that is that the neutron does possess a non-zero spin. This means that while the neutron doesn't interact with electric force, it can react to an external magnetic field (a fact that is applied in nuclear magnetic resonance).

Comment: Does the fact that neutrons are made up of quarks (which are charged) affect this explanation at all?

Comment: While it is true that quarks do possess charge, the fact is that quarks in a neutron (which add up to zero) are so closely bound together by the strong nuclear force that they cannot feel the electromagnetic force of the proton. However, I'm not aware if there could be a extreme case where an external electric field could indeed affect the very quarks in neutron (maybe someone else can point it out).

Comment: Nevertheless, I forgot to mention there's indeed a contribution from the quarks themselves to the neutron, and that is that the neutron does possess a non-zero spin. This means that while the neutron doesn't interact with electric force, it can react to an external magnetic field (a fact that is applied in nuclear magnetic resonance).

Comment: @Charlie: I would suggest that you edit your answer to include the material in that comment.

Comment: Protons and neutrons certainly do interact magnetically, so your bolded sentence is wrong.

Comment: You're right, this actually contradicts what I said after. Let me edit the answer.